# Azure API Management + VNET to protect Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to create an API Management service that's within an external virtual network and using an Azure Function App as the backend. The virtual network is set up to allow only a specific range of IP addresses in, and I've set up the outbound rules [as per this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#a-namenetwork-configuration-issues-acommon-network-configuration-issues).

Unfortunately when I try to hit the endpoint surfaced by API Management through the portal, I receive the following HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

content-length: 53
vary: Origin
content-type: application/json
{
    "error": "Unable to connect to the remote server"
}
```

If I hit the API Management request URL with `curl` I get a 404 response but no body. If I hit a URL that's not actually part of the API Management service, I get a 404 response with a proper body.

If I hit the endpoint surfaced by the Function App I get the response I expect, so that at least is working well.

I've even gone so far as to completely open up the Network Security Group on the virtual network to allow all traffic inbound and outbound and that has no effect.

Is it even possible to use a virtual network to restrict access to an API Management service backed by a Function App in this way? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using Consumption Plan? If yes, VNET is not a supported scenario at the moment.

Comment: I am using a Consumption Plan and I know that putting a Function App into a VNET isn't supported, but the API Management service that is in the VNET should still be able to access something that's outside of the VNET, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try using APIM tracing to see if APIM is even invoked/reached for various types of requests. In addition, try testing with both Azure portal and APIM developer portal. The latter sends requests to APIM service "locally". Knowing how requests behave in different conditions should help identify the issue.